# Do positrons annihilate in a vacuum?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, vacuum, antimatter

Seems like a stupid question as positrons only annihilate when they encounter an electron and it may be possible that they encounter an electron even in a supposedly perfect 'vacuum', however I was wondering if anyone knows of any experiments conducted on positrons in vacua or if there's any theoretical support for the idea that they annihilate spontaneously, or something like that.

Answer (score 2):

A positron spontaneously "annihilating" as you describe would be what particle physicists refer to as a "decay," where a particle turns into two or more other particles spontaneously. Under the Standard Model, and many (most?) extensions to the Standard Model, the electron and the positron are both stable. This is because electric charge is conserved, and there are no lighter charged particles for them to decay into.

Experimentally, the lifetime of an electron is known to be longer than $6.6\times10^{28}~\rm years$, as listed by the [Particle Data Group](http://pdg.lbl.gov/2017/tables/rpp2017-sum-leptons.pdf). Theoretically, the electron and the positron have the same lifetime, and so this same measurement can be applied to the positron as well.

Comment: But there haven't been any experiments with positrons?

Comment: @SamCottle There have been, but I don't know the limits off the top of my head. Experimentally they would certainly be worse than the limits for an electron.